# I want to extract the phone numbers from this page that has a onclick event using selenium on python

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, selenium

the html code is provided in the picture.

I have tried the following attempt:

```
content = soup.find_all('div', {"class": ["listing_category_business company_profile", "listing_category_business free_listing"]})
```

for company in content:

```
phoneIcon = driver.find_element_by_xpath\
            ("/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/span").get_attribute("dcl_val.tel")
```

the return output is:

> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
> (session="cdefcfd5b11ca18dc9c30ebb6ae1b2ba",
> element="37a78fe4-028c-4555-87a0-964738626fcb")>

There are 10 different numbers to extract from this page, all with a different id, so I can't use that to use `find_element_by_xpath()`. Are there any solutions for the following issue?
Apologies if the solution is easy to solve as I just started using Selenium yesterday and I am still figuring things out.

The html page is :
https://www.streetdirectory.com/businessfinder/company/505/Cleaning_Services/All/2/

Comment: When you say 10 different id's....for which element did you mean ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the "dcl_val.business_id" right after the onclick="".

Comment: I am unable to figure out how to extract the value from "dcl_val.tel" and hope to get assistance on that. For example, dcl_val.tel = '6735 2000'. I wish to be able to extract '6735 2000'

Comment: `"/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/span")`  - Does this path remains constant for all of them ?

Comment: No, I was trying out a new method, but I dont think it is constant. 
The following statement is constant : 
phoneIcon = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'https://x2.sdimgs.com/img/business_finder/tel-icon.png')]")

Comment: Since dcl_val.business_id or any dcl_* key,value pairs are all inside onclick event attribute. So first fetch the value for attribute and next you either split by semicolon or use regex to extract the specific value u r looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, substitute i with numbers like(1,2...n) to get first, second, third.... nth phone numbers

```
phoneIcon = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//td[text()='Tel'])[" + i + "]/following::td[contains(@class,'Link')][1]//span").get_attribute("dcl_val.tel")
```

I am not familiar with python selenium, otherwise I would have given for loop logic to iterate through all phone numbers and get them.